# Pagination in Hibernate 3

Tags: sql, hibernate, pagination

I am using

```
queryObj.setFirstResult(pageOffset);
queryObj.setMaxResults(limitInt)
```

for accomplishing pagination in my hibernate program.

However, when i do a `System.out.println(queryObj)` after i have executed my query it isn't displaying the corresponding sql query.

Is that part kept **abstract** to the users by hibernate as its security feature?

Also is this called as back end pagination?

Kindly post any links /references

Answer (score 0):

configure log4j and set TRACE level as follows

```
log4j.logger.org.hibernate=TRACE
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=TRACE
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.engine.query=TRACE
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type=TRACE
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.jdbc=TRACE
```

taken from

**[How To Debug Hibernate SQL Queries With Parameters](http://blog.aplikacja.info/2010/03/how-to-debug-hibernate-sql-queries-with-parameters/)**

hope this will help you !